# Retrieve all email address of gmail contacts and display in android

Tags: android, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

I have tried using oAuth 2.0 but couldn't setup this. In my application I need to setup an invitation flow, where when the user log in with gmail on button click, all the contact's email addresses are stored in a list and invitation is sent.

For this flow I need to get all the email address list of the user.

I have tried Google plus api also, its working but can't get the email addresses, only name, profile data are fetched!

Any solutions?

Comment: are you got the answer for this?